# Coding a *small* Button Addon in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Looking at this doc: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons specifically the section called "Button Addons" to learn how to code a combination search box and button as illustrated there. I used the code in the example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Now, I want to make the text box and the button 'small' (-sm) or even extra small (-xs) but referring to the source css, and trying various permutations I can't get it to work.

Here is the closest I've gotten:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <form role="form" class="form-inline" action="/search_index/search/index.html">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
      <input type="text" name="q" id="tipue_search_input" class="form-control">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" 
                  id="tipue_search_button" onclick="this.form.submit();">
                  find
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Is this a hole in Bootstrap or a fix I can use?

Comment: sm and xs doesn't say small of extra small.. It hase to do with the resolution. You should read the documentation of Bootstrap better

Comment: @GusDB, that's true of columns, not of buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bs3 you can only use these 2 classes for input groups:

`input-sm` and `input-lg`

They work for me. This is how you use it:

```
 <div class="input-group input-sm">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Comment: These got renamed to `input-group-sm` and `input-group-lg`.